# Electron / Node file path location

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron app that is using [electron-log](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log) to handle creating some debugging information for the app. By default, it is saving the files to the following location per the module:

```
**on macOS:** ~/Library/Logs/<app name>/log.log

**on Windows:** %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\<app name>\log.log
```

I have added an option in the menu to "View Debug Info". My goal is to read this log into a textarea (on a renderer) so that they can provide it to support if needed.

In my renderer, I am using `fs` in order to access the file system but I can't find anything in `process.env` that points to these locations so I assume they are custom?

Is there a variable I am missing that contains these paths on the os?

```
const fs = require('fs');

if(process.platform == 'darwin'){
    // Path is ~/Library/Logs/<app name>/log.log
    // Read the file into the textarea
}else{
    // Path is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\<app name>\log.log
    // Read the file into the textarea
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const log = require('electron-log');

const path = log.transports.file.findLogPath();
```

[findLogPath.js#L17](https://github.com/megahertz/electron-log/blob/4e53706d54929dc7aca4b24da537d3e3b02163e2/lib/transports/file/findLogPath.js#L17)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `app.getPath(...)` in your case.

```
import { app } from "electron";
let logFileName;

// If, darwin; PATH is: ~/Library/Logs/<app name>/log.log
if(process.platform == 'darwin'){
  logFileName = app.getPath("logs") + "/log.log",
} else if(process.platform == 'win32'){ {
  logFileName = app.getPath("userData") + "/log.log",
} else {
  // Handle other supported platforms ('aix','freebsd', 'linux', 'openbsd', 'sunos')
}

fs.readFile(logFileName, function read(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  // Read the file data content into the text-area.
});
```

From Electron's `getPath` [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname);

> `app.getPath(name)`
>
> name `String`
>
> Returns `String` - A path to a special directory or file associated with name. On failure, an Error is thrown.
>
> You can request the following paths by the `name`:
>
> `home` User's home directory.
>
> `appData` Per-user application data directory, which by default points to: `%APPDATA%` on Windows, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or `~/.config` on Linux & `~/Library/Application Support` on macOS
>
> `userData` The directory for storing your app's configuration files, which by default it is the appData directory appended with your app's name.
>
> `temp` Temporary directory.
>
> `exe` The current executable file.
>
> `module` The libchromiumcontent library.
>
> `desktop` The current user's Desktop directory.
>
> `documents` Directory for a user's "My Documents".
>
> `downloads` Directory for a user's downloads.
>
> `music` Directory for a user's music.
>
> `pictures` Directory for a user's pictures.
>
> `videos` Directory for a user's videos.
>
> `logs` Directory for your app's log folder.
>
> `pepperFlashSystemPlugin` Full path to the system version of the Pepper Flash plugin.